# Matrix representations of $\mathfrak{g}^*$.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $g = sl_2$. Then there is a matrix representation of $g$ as follows. The Lie algebra $g$ is a three dimensional vector space with a basis $E, F, H$ such that $[E,F]=H$,$[H,E]=2E$,$[H,F]=-2F$. The elements $E, F, H$ have matrix representations: $E = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)$, $F = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)$, $H = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{matrix} \right)$.

Let $g^*$ be the dual vector space of $g$. The vector space $g^*$ is has a dual basis $E^*, F^*, H^*$. Under the bracket $[E^*, F^*]=0$, $[H^*, E^*]=\frac{1}{4}E^*$, $[H^*, F^*]=\frac{1}{4}F^*$, $g^*$ becomes a Lie algebra.

My question is: are there some matrix representations of $E^*, F^*, H^*$? Thank you very much.

Comment: The dual basis (relative to the trace form) to $(E,F,H)$ is $(E^*,F^*,H^*)=(F,E,H/2)$, so $[E^*,F^*]=[F,E]=-H=-2H^*$, and not $[E^*,F^*]=0$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, thank you very much. But the brackets on $g^*$ is given in Section 1.1 on page 6 of [the paper](http://www.math.polytechnique.fr/cmat/kosmann/lnp2.pdf). It is said that $[E^*, F^*]=0$. I am confused.

Comment: On page $13$ they do the computation again. The claim is, that the double should be isomorphic to $sl(2)\oplus sl(2)$. First I thought, that perhaps we need $[E^*,F^*]=-8H^*$ for this. You should try to compute the Jacobi identity for $\mathfrak{g}\bowtie \mathfrak{g}^{\ast}$, and test all claims explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lie algebra you described doesn't really have much to do with $\mathfrak{sl}_{2}$ because you just described an arbitrary bracket on a 3 dimensional vector space. This Lie algebra has a fairly simple faithful matrix representation as

$$H \mapsto \left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)$$

$$E \mapsto \left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)$$

$$F \mapsto \left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)$$

Alternatively, you can also view the Lie algebra as the Lie algebra of the group of transformations of the plane that are built out of scaling and translation.

Answer (score 1):

Every finite-dimensional Lie algebra has a faithful matrix representation by a theorem of Ado and Iwasawa. The proof is not so easy. However, if the Lie algebra has trivial center, we can just take the adjoint representation given by $x\mapsto ad(x)$, where $ad(x)(y)=[x,y]$. 
The solvable Lie algebra of dimension $3$, which you have given, has trivial center. Hence the adjoint representation is a faithful matrix representation of dimension $3$.